# How to Set Valid Lookup?

Tags: apex, trigger, class, childrecords

I am in the process of validating a trigger that invokes a class that will perform calculations on a child object.  I keep getting the error below.  I know how to fix the error but when I add the Premium_Rate__c to the test class I lose all of my code coverage.

Here is my Trigger:

```
trigger onDependent on dependant__c (before insert, before update) {
onNewDependent.newRow(trigger.new);
}
```

Here is my test class:

```
@isTest
public class testOnDependent {

@isTest
public static void verifyChange()
{
    Premium_Rate__c rate = new Premium_Rate__c();
    string name = rate.Name = 'john';
    dependant__c dep = new dependant__c(name='sdkjflsdkfj',
                                       // id='1111',
                                       // Premium_Rate__c = 'test',
                                        //Premium_Rate__c = 'sdklsd',
                                        Age__c ='99',
                                        relationship__c = 'Dependent',
                                        Rating_Region__c='Region 1',
                                        age_rate__c = 1.000,
                                        Plan_Rate__c = 1.000,
                                        sequence_number__c = 1);
    //if (dep.Premium_Rate__c!=null)
    insert dep;
   // insert dep.Premium_Rate__c = 'bob';        
    Test.startTest();

    dep.Age__c = '65';
    dep.relationship__c = 'Spouse';
    dep.Rating_Region__c='Region 1';
    dep.Plan_Rate__c = 1.000;
    update dep;       
    dep.Age__c = '21';
    dep.Rating_Region__c='Region 2';
    dep.relationship__c = 'Dependent';
    dep.Premium_Rate__c = 'bob';
    update dep; 
    dep.age_rate__c = 1.000;
    dep.Age__c = '22';
    update dep; 

    test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Here is my class:

```
public class onNewDependent { 

    static final Decimal fallbackRate = 3.000;
    static final map<string, Decimal> ageToRate = new map<String, Decimal>
    {
        '0'=>.635,'1'=>.635,'2'=>.635,'2'=>.635,'3'=>.635,'4'=>.635,'5'=>.635,'6'=>.635,'7'=>.635,'8'=>.635,
        '9'=>.635,'10'=>.635,'11'=>.635,'12'=>.635,'13'=>.635,'14'=>.635,'15'=>.635,'16'=>.635,'17'=>.635,
        '18'=>.635,'19'=>.635,'20'=>.635,'21'=>1.000,'22'=>1.000,'23'=>1.000,'24'=>1.000,'25'=>1.004,
        '26'=>1.024,'27'=>1.048,'28'=>1.087,'29'=>1.119,'30'=>1.135,'31'=>1.159,'32'=>1.183,'33'=>1.198,
        '34'=>1.214,'35'=>1.222,'36'=>1.23,'37'=>1.238,'38'=>1.246,'39'=>1.262,'40'=>1.278,'41'=>1.302,'42'=>1.325,
        '43'=>1.357,'44'=>1.397,'45'=>1.444,'46'=>1.5,'47'=>1.563,'48'=>1.635,'49'=>1.706,'50'=>1.786,'51'=>1.865,
        '52'=>1.952,'53'=>2.02,'54'=>2.135,'55'=>2.23,'56'=>2.333,'57'=>2.437,'58'=>2.548,'59'=>2.603,'60'=>2.714,
        '61'=>2.81,'62'=>2.873,'63'=>2.952,'64'=>3.000,'65'=>3.000
    };
public static void newRow(dependant__c[] depdts)
{

    Premium_Rate__c rate = new Premium_Rate__c();
    for (dependant__c dep :depdts)
    {

        if (ageToRate.containsKey(dep.Age__c)){dep.age_rate__c = ageToRate.get(dep.age__c);}
        else{dep.age_rate__c = fallbackRate;}

        if (String.isNotBlank(dep.rating_region__c))
        {
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 1'))
            {dep.rating_region_number__c=1.000;}
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 2')){dep.rating_region_number__c=1.009;}      
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 3')){dep.rating_region_number__c=0.984;}  
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 4')){dep.rating_region_number__c=1.033;}
        }
     /*
        Set<Id> rateIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Dependant__c record : dependants) rateIds.add(record.Premium_Rate__c);
            Map<Id, Premium_Rate__c> rates = new Map<Id, Premium_Rate__c>([
                SELECT Base_Rate__c, Individual_Plan_Rate__c , Plan_rate__c
                FROM Premium_Rate__c WHERE Id IN :rateIds
            ]);
            for (Dependant record : dependants)
            {
                Premium_Rate__c rate = rates.get(record.Premium_Rate__c);
                if (rate != null)
                {
                    // now you can get your Decimal values safely.
                }
        }
        */   
        ////////dsfdsfdsfds//////////// 
     decimal  baseRate = 0;
        if (dep.Premium_Rate__c != null)
        {
        baseRate = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Base_Rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c WHERE Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Base_Rate__c;

        decimal ayy = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Plan_rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c where Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Plan_rate__c;
        string aplus = String.valueOf(ayy);

        decimal byy = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Individual_Plan_Rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c where Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Individual_Plan_Rate__c;


        if(string.isEmpty(aplus)){dep.Plan_Rate__c = byy;}
        else{dep.Plan_Rate__c = ayy;}
        }    
        else{baseRate = 0;}
        ///////sdds////////
        if((dep.sequence_number__c<=3 && (dep.Age__c.equals('0')||dep.Age__c.equals('1')||dep.Age__c.equals('2')||dep.Age__c.equals('3')||dep.Age__c.equals('4')||dep.Age__c.equals('5')||dep.Age__c.equals('6')||dep.Age__c.equals('7')||dep.Age__c.equals('8')||dep.Age__c.equals('9')||dep.Age__c.equals('10')||dep.Age__c.equals('11')||dep.Age__c.equals('12')||dep.Age__c.equals('13')||dep.Age__c.equals('14')||dep.Age__c.equals('15')||dep.Age__c.equals('16')||dep.Age__c.equals('17')||dep.Age__c.equals('18')||dep.Age__c.equals('19')||dep.Age__c.equals('20')||dep.Age__c.equals('21'))&& dep.relationship__c.equals('Dependent'))||(dep.relationship__c.equals('Dependent')&& (dep.Age__c.equals('22')||dep.Age__c.equals('23')||dep.Age__c.equals('24')||dep.Age__c.equals('25')||dep.Age__c.equals('26')||dep.Age__c.equals('27')||dep.Age__c.equals('28')||dep.Age__c.equals('29')||dep.Age__c.equals('30')||dep.Age__c.equals('31')||dep.Age__c.equals('32')||dep.Age__c.equals('33')||dep.Age__c.equals('34')||dep.Age__c.equals('35')||dep.Age__c.equals('36')||dep.Age__c.equals('37')||dep.Age__c.equals('38')||dep.Age__c.equals('39')||dep.Age__c.equals('40')||dep.Age__c.equals('41')||dep.Age__c.equals('42')||dep.Age__c.equals('43')||dep.Age__c.equals('44')||dep.Age__c.equals('45')||dep.Age__c.equals('46')||dep.Age__c.equals('47')||dep.Age__c.equals('48')||dep.Age__c.equals('49')||dep.Age__c.equals('50')||dep.Age__c.equals('51')||dep.Age__c.equals('52')||dep.Age__c.equals('53')||dep.Age__c.equals('54')||dep.Age__c.equals('55')||dep.Age__c.equals('56')||dep.Age__c.equals('57')||dep.Age__c.equals('58')||dep.Age__c.equals('59')||dep.Age__c.equals('60')||dep.Age__c.equals('61')||dep.Age__c.equals('62')||dep.Age__c.equals('63')||dep.Age__c.equals('64')||dep.Age__c.equals('65')||dep.Age__c.equals('66')||dep.Age__c.equals('67')||dep.Age__c.equals('68')||dep.Age__c.equals('69')||dep.Age__c.equals('70')||dep.Age__c.equals('71')||dep.Age__c.equals('72')||dep.Age__c.equals('73')||dep.Age__c.equals('74')||dep.Age__c.equals('75')||dep.Age__c.equals('76')||dep.Age__c.equals('77')||dep.Age__c.equals('78')||dep.Age__c.equals('79')||dep.Age__c.equals('80')||dep.Age__c.equals('81')||dep.Age__c.equals('82')||dep.Age__c.equals('83')||dep.Age__c.equals('84')||dep.Age__c.equals('85')||dep.Age__c.equals('86')||dep.Age__c.equals('87')||dep.Age__c.equals('88')||dep.Age__c.equals('89')||dep.Age__c.equals('90')||dep.Age__c.equals('91')||dep.Age__c.equals('92')||dep.Age__c.equals('93')||dep.Age__c.equals('94')||dep.Age__c.equals('95')||dep.Age__c.equals('96')||dep.Age__c.equals('97')||dep.Age__c.equals('98')||dep.Age__c.equals('99')||dep.Age__c.equals('100')))||dep.relationship__c.equals('Spouse'))
        dep.final_rate__c = dep.Plan_rate__c*baseRate*dep.age_rate__c*dep.rating_region_number__c;            

    }
}
}
```

Here is my error code:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Premium_Rate__c]: [Premium_Rate__c]
>   Stack Trace: Class.testOnDependent.verifyChange: line 20, column 1

Comment: All of it, or some of it? It doesn't make a lot of sense for all of it to be gone. Can you confirm? If "some" of it, what lines remain uncovered?

Comment: I feel for you Andy -- the distinction between dependent and dependant http://grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/dependant_dependent.htm -- unless the org created `dependant__c` misspelled

Comment: @sebastian Kessel I lose all of my code coverage, without the Premium_rate__c I have 81% coverage and with it I have 0% coverage.  premium_rate__c also refers to dependent__c's parent object

Comment: unfortunately that was me...

Comment: If it's a lookup, have you tried setting a real Id? The code that is commented would set gibberish.

Comment: Your helper class has SOQL inside of for loop - this is going to be a problem. You need to query for the Rates outside of the for loop; stuff them into maps, and then refer to them as you process the triggered objects

Answer (score 1):

You still have serious bulkification issues. But, you should be able to resolve the cause for your posted exception message by inserting your `Premium_Rate__c` record and then using its `Id` in the `Premium_Rate__c` field on your `Dependant__c` record.

```
Premium_Rate__c rate = new Premium_Rate__c(/*required field-value pairs*/);
insert rate;

Dependant__c dependant = new Dependant__c(Premium_Rate__c = rate.Id, /*other fields*/);
//rest of test
```

Comment: I found that this worked but I the test class is not giving 0% coverage for the trigger, which means its not checking the main class