# Trigger not triggering from test class

Tags: apex, trigger, class

Not sure why the trigger isn't firing from the test class.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

My code validation is 0% for the trigger and it doesn't check the main class.  I assume that is because it doesn't get past the trigger......

whats interesting is when the test is run without referencing the parent object it goes through the trigger just fine and I get 81% code coverage.
trigger:

```
trigger onDependent on dependant__c (before insert, before update) {
    onNewDependent.newRow(trigger.new);
}
```

Code:

```
public class onNewDependent { 

public static void newRow(dependant__c[] depdts)
{
    final Decimal fallbackRate = 3.000;
    final map<string, Decimal> ageToRate = new map<String, Decimal>
    {
        '0'=>.635,'1'=>.635,'2'=>.635,'2'=>.635,'3'=>.635,'4'=>.635,'5'=>.635,'6'=>.635,'7'=>.635,'8'=>.635,
        '9'=>.635,'10'=>.635,'11'=>.635,'12'=>.635,'13'=>.635,'14'=>.635,'15'=>.635,'16'=>.635,'17'=>.635,
        '18'=>.635,'19'=>.635,'20'=>.635,'21'=>1.000,'22'=>1.000,'23'=>1.000,'24'=>1.000,'25'=>1.004,
        '26'=>1.024,'27'=>1.048,'28'=>1.087,'29'=>1.119,'30'=>1.135,'31'=>1.159,'32'=>1.183,'33'=>1.198,
        '34'=>1.214,'35'=>1.222,'36'=>1.23,'37'=>1.238,'38'=>1.246,'39'=>1.262,'40'=>1.278,'41'=>1.302,'42'=>1.325,
        '43'=>1.357,'44'=>1.397,'45'=>1.444,'46'=>1.5,'47'=>1.563,'48'=>1.635,'49'=>1.706,'50'=>1.786,'51'=>1.865,
        '52'=>1.952,'53'=>2.02,'54'=>2.135,'55'=>2.23,'56'=>2.333,'57'=>2.437,'58'=>2.548,'59'=>2.603,'60'=>2.714,
        '61'=>2.81,'62'=>2.873,'63'=>2.952,'64'=>3.000,'65'=>3.000
    };
    Premium_Rate__c rate = new Premium_Rate__c();
    for (dependant__c dep :depdts)
    {

        if (ageToRate.containsKey(dep.Age__c)){dep.age_rate__c = ageToRate.get(dep.age__c);}
        else{dep.age_rate__c = fallbackRate;}

        if (String.isNotBlank(dep.rating_region__c))
        {
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 1'))
            {dep.rating_region_number__c=1.000;}
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 2')){dep.rating_region_number__c=1.009;}      
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 3')){dep.rating_region_number__c=0.984;}  
            if(dep.rating_region__c.contains('Region 4')){dep.rating_region_number__c=1.033;}
        }
     decimal  baseRate = 0;
        if (dep.Premium_Rate__c != null)
        {
            baseRate = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Base_Rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c WHERE Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Base_Rate__c;

            decimal ayy = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Plan_rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c where Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Plan_rate__c;
            string aplus = String.valueOf(ayy);
            decimal byy = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Individual_Plan_Rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c where Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Individual_Plan_Rate__c;


            if(string.isEmpty(aplus)){dep.Plan_Rate__c = byy;}
            else{dep.Plan_Rate__c = ayy;}
        }    
        else{baseRate = 0;}
        if (dep.sequence_number__c !=0||string.isNotBlank(dep.relationship__c)){
        if((dep.sequence_number__c<=3 && (dep.Age__c.equals('0')||dep.Age__c.equals('1')||dep.Age__c.equals('2')||dep.Age__c.equals('3')||dep.Age__c.equals('4')||dep.Age__c.equals('5')||dep.Age__c.equals('6')||dep.Age__c.equals('7')||dep.Age__c.equals('8')||dep.Age__c.equals('9')||dep.Age__c.equals('10')||dep.Age__c.equals('11')||dep.Age__c.equals('12')||dep.Age__c.equals('13')||dep.Age__c.equals('14')||dep.Age__c.equals('15')||dep.Age__c.equals('16')||dep.Age__c.equals('17')||dep.Age__c.equals('18')||dep.Age__c.equals('19')||dep.Age__c.equals('20')||dep.Age__c.equals('21'))&& dep.relationship__c.equals('Dependent'))||(dep.relationship__c.equals('Dependent')&& (dep.Age__c.equals('22')||dep.Age__c.equals('23')||dep.Age__c.equals('24')||dep.Age__c.equals('25')||dep.Age__c.equals('26')||dep.Age__c.equals('27')||dep.Age__c.equals('28')||dep.Age__c.equals('29')||dep.Age__c.equals('30')||dep.Age__c.equals('31')||dep.Age__c.equals('32')||dep.Age__c.equals('33')||dep.Age__c.equals('34')||dep.Age__c.equals('35')||dep.Age__c.equals('36')||dep.Age__c.equals('37')||dep.Age__c.equals('38')||dep.Age__c.equals('39')||dep.Age__c.equals('40')||dep.Age__c.equals('41')||dep.Age__c.equals('42')||dep.Age__c.equals('43')||dep.Age__c.equals('44')||dep.Age__c.equals('45')||dep.Age__c.equals('46')||dep.Age__c.equals('47')||dep.Age__c.equals('48')||dep.Age__c.equals('49')||dep.Age__c.equals('50')||dep.Age__c.equals('51')||dep.Age__c.equals('52')||dep.Age__c.equals('53')||dep.Age__c.equals('54')||dep.Age__c.equals('55')||dep.Age__c.equals('56')||dep.Age__c.equals('57')||dep.Age__c.equals('58')||dep.Age__c.equals('59')||dep.Age__c.equals('60')||dep.Age__c.equals('61')||dep.Age__c.equals('62')||dep.Age__c.equals('63')||dep.Age__c.equals('64')||dep.Age__c.equals('65')||dep.Age__c.equals('66')||dep.Age__c.equals('67')||dep.Age__c.equals('68')||dep.Age__c.equals('69')||dep.Age__c.equals('70')||dep.Age__c.equals('71')||dep.Age__c.equals('72')||dep.Age__c.equals('73')||dep.Age__c.equals('74')||dep.Age__c.equals('75')||dep.Age__c.equals('76')||dep.Age__c.equals('77')||dep.Age__c.equals('78')||dep.Age__c.equals('79')||dep.Age__c.equals('80')||dep.Age__c.equals('81')||dep.Age__c.equals('82')||dep.Age__c.equals('83')||dep.Age__c.equals('84')||dep.Age__c.equals('85')||dep.Age__c.equals('86')||dep.Age__c.equals('87')||dep.Age__c.equals('88')||dep.Age__c.equals('89')||dep.Age__c.equals('90')||dep.Age__c.equals('91')||dep.Age__c.equals('92')||dep.Age__c.equals('93')||dep.Age__c.equals('94')||dep.Age__c.equals('95')||dep.Age__c.equals('96')||dep.Age__c.equals('97')||dep.Age__c.equals('98')||dep.Age__c.equals('99')||dep.Age__c.equals('100')))||dep.relationship__c.equals('Spouse'))
        dep.final_rate__c = dep.Plan_rate__c*baseRate*dep.age_rate__c*dep.rating_region_number__c;            
        } 
    }
}
```

}

Test Class:

```
@isTest
public class testOnDependent {
@isTest
public static void verifyChange()
{
    Premium_Rate__c rate = new Premium_Rate__c(/**/Name = 'john',
                                              Age_Del__c = '30',
                                              Plan__c = 'CS',
                                              Rating_Region__c = 'region 1',
                                              Relationship__c = 'Single');
    insert rate;

    dependant__c dep = new dependant__c(
                                        Premium_rate__c = rate.Name,
                                        name='wife',
                                        Age__c ='99',
                                        relationship__c = 'Dependent',
                                        Rating_Region__c= 'Region 1',
                                        sequence_number__c = 1);
    insert dep;
    Test.startTest();
    rate.Name = 'john';
    dep.Premium_Rate__c = rate.Name;
    dep.Age__c = '65';
    dep.sequence_number__c = 1;
    dep.relationship__c = 'Spouse';
    dep.Rating_Region__c='Region 1';
    update dep;       
    dep.Age__c = '21';
    dep.Rating_Region__c='Region 2';
    dep.relationship__c = 'Dependent';
    update dep; 
    dep.Age__c = '22';
    update dep;
    test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this? `@isTest
public static void verifyChange()
{}`

I've only ever done `public testMethod  static void verifyChange()`

Comment: yeah, i mean it works for me.  Ive used it before with no problems

Comment: So you're Trigger is getting 0 coverage, I would expect that to be 100, but maybe your class is getting 0, can you confirm that

Comment: Yeah. When I run the test I get 0%, whats interesting is when the test is run without referencing the parent object it goes through the trigger just fine and I get 81% code coverage. - i should put that on an edit

Comment: What's the parent object?

Comment: Premium_Rate__c

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36749/discussion-between-ericssh-and-andy-scott).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set Valid Lookup?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/113461/how-to-set-valid-lookup)

Comment: same program, different problem

Comment: (1) in your test setup, the line ` Premium_rate__c = rate.Name,` can't be right, this is a lookup field and should be set to  `rate.id`. I'm astonished you didn't get an exception; and as an aside, your `ageToRate` map should be externalized to an sobject for ease of maintenance (rates always go up :-)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests) (emphasis mine):

> #### Verify the results are correct
>
> Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. *Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests.* They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing_(software)), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests.

In this case, there are a few different things you can assert on, but the one that jumps out at me as most obvious is that your age to rate mapping should populate:

```
system.assertEquals(3, dependant.Age_Rate__c, 'The rate should be set based on age');
```

If this assertion passes, then you at least know the trigger is running, regardless of the coverage number.

Also, your trigger is terribly bulkified. Take this snippet:

```
 baseRate = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Base_Rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c WHERE Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Base_Rate__c;
 decimal ayy = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Plan_rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c where Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Plan_rate__c;
 string aplus = String.valueOf(ayy);
 decimal byy = [SELECT Premium_Rate__c.Individual_Plan_Rate__c FROM Premium_Rate__c where Premium_Rate__c.id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c].Individual_Plan_Rate__c;
```

Besides the fact this is in a loop and you **shouldn't do any queries here**, you are using 3x as many queries as you need *within the loop*. At least change it to:

```
Premium_Rate__c rate = [
    SELECT Base_Rate__c, Individual_Plan_Rate__c, Plan_Rate__c
    FROM Premium_Rate__c WHERE Id = :dep.Premium_Rate__c
];
Decimal baseRate = rate.Base_Rate__c;
Decimal planRate = rate.Plan_Rate__c;
Decimal individualPlanRate = rate.Individual_Plan_Rate__c;
dependant.Plan_Rate__c = (planRate != null) ? planRate : individualPlanRate;
```

Comment: well I took your suggestion and rewrote my code to only produce 1 query. as for rewriting everything so the query doesn't need to be in the loop, I don't think I have the time to rewrite this to do that.

Comment: @AndyScott And did your assertions pass?

Comment: Yes my assertion passed, but I'm still receiving the validation error.

Comment: @AndyScott - I guarantee that, you or your successor will realize that writing the trigger properly bulkified would have been the right thing to do in the first place.